# How can I say "cozy"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Neither Revo nor Lernu gave me any results. I tried both the American and British spellings.

These are some keywords from a website defining "cozy": *small*, *warm*, *comfortable*, *pleasant*, *friendly*. Maybe it is possible to work from there.

Answer (score 8):

If *cosy (cozy)* is *komforta, varma, intima* it must be *hejmeca* or even *hejma*.

Answer (score 6):

I tried looking for the equivalent Bulgarian/Russian word *уют* in ReVo. I found a translation for the Russian one there, and it gives: ***komfort/o***. I guess there is not a more specific one, at least in ReVo.

---

Mi provis serĉi la egalsignifan bulgaran/rusan vorton *уют* en ReVo. Mi trovis, ke estas traduko por la rusa, kaj ĝi estas: ***komfort/o***. Mi supozas, ke ne ekzistas pli ĝusta vorto, almenaŭ en ReVo.

Answer (score 5):

Ultimately, the focus needs to be expressing ideas and not translating words. Think about the idea you're trying to express and ask yourself what Esperanto words can express that idea. You're on the right track looking at the keywords from the definition. Another method could be to check an English-language thesaurus.

- comfortable
- comfy
- cushy
- intimate
- snug
- safe

Do any of these express your idea? What do you find in a bilingual dictionary for them? Do the definitions of those translations express your idea? *Komforta* is a very good suggestion, but the question really is whether this expresses **your** idea, and only you can answer that.

Another thing you could consider is getting a paper dictionary. Benson (CEED) actually has an entry for "cozy" - which includes *komforta* and *gemuta*. The latter is from the PIVS and doesn't seem to be in overly wide use.

Answer (score 3):

In [John Wells’ dictionary](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176) there is:

> **cozy** komforta, varma, intima

Maybe the best solution would be to just use both words: *mi ŝatas la etoson de la gufujo, ĝi estas komforta kaj intima*.

Answer (score 2):

*Cosy* is a combination of *comfortable, warm, enclosed, safe*.

The closest, most general equivalent is *gemuta* (based on *gemütlich* from German—try a Google Image Search on that word), followed by *hejmeca* (homely). If I didn't like either I might try a compound, *tuŝvarma*, *nestbela*, or *hejmtuŝa* or something like that.

Other words and expressions you may consider are:

- *tuŝanta sceno* (touching scene), *sereniga vidaĵo* (calming sight)
- *remburita* (upholstered), *pufeca* (puffy), *kuseneca* (cushiony)
- *molmola* (utterly soft), *lanugeca* (downy, fig.), *liteca* (bedlike)
- *anguleto* (nook), *ĉambreto* (little room), *nesteca* (nestlike), *ĉirkaŭbrakeca* ("hugsome")